# CROSS APPLY function in Presto/AWS

Tags: sql-server, presto, amazon-athena

I'm trying to convert 4 date columns titled Created, Approved, Processed & Realized to a single column with all 4 dates AND a second column with the status of each of those dates.

*The image at the end shows the data issue visually (apologies I'm still figuring out how to attach tables in textual form on stackoverflow)*

> To solve this, I successfully executed the CROSS APPLY
> function in SQL server (see below), but I now need to do the same in AWS Simba
> Athena or the Presto language. Can someone please guide me on what is the AWS/Presto equivalent of a CROSS APPLY function? Thank you in advance

```
SELECT 

    V.Date,
    V.Status
    From Table C
    CROSS APPLY     
        (VALUES 
                (C.Created, 'Opened'), 
                (C.Approved, 'Approved'), 
                (C.Processed, 'Processed'), 
                (C.Realized, 'Realized')
                                                 ) AS V([Date], Status)
```

I want to convert the following table:

[image]

Comment: It seems you're looking after [`UNNEST`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest)?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Do you maybe have an example to share of how we can use columns in this function instead of arrays?

Comment: Added an answer. If you need more help, you can always get it on `#troubleshooting` channel on [Presto community slack](https://prestosql.io/slack.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use [`UNNEST`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) for this:

```
SELECT v.date, v.status
FROM m_table
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(ARRAY[
 ROW(C.Created, 'Opened'), 
 ROW(C.Approved, 'Approved'), 
 ROW(C.Processed, 'Processed'), 
 ROW(C.Realized, 'Realized')
]) AS v(date, status);
```

This works in the latest Presto version, 337.

In Athena you probably still cannot UNNEST array or ROW
in ANSI SQL manner, so you may need some modifications.